# SharePoint 2016 Custom Server Role

Tags: 2016, minrole

I'm considering adding a custom server role to our 2016 farm plan. I notice though that the TechNet article describing services on the different MinRoles states that the custom server role has the distributed cache activated?

That seems unusual to me. Can someone confirm whether this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

In MinRole, the **Custom Server Role** include the below services

- Distributed Cache
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Administration
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application

These default services are auto-provisioned by default in Custom Server Role based on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx).

---

**Note:**

- In Custom Server Role, it's supported to start any services on the server with out any issue otherwise other server roles it will raise a health analyzer warning.

Check MinRole and its associated services for each server role at [MinRole Server Roles in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx)